# Existence of algorithm predicting next bit in output sequence

Tags: random-number-generator, randomness, pseudo-random-generator

Let $X = [0, 1]\cap \mathbb{Q}$, and let $f:X \rightarrow X$ be a chaotic map (i.e. the logistic map with rational parameter).  My question is as follows, and is purely theoretical in nature.  Pick some value $x_0$ from $X$ (note that $X$ is infinite here, so pick a value using the axiom of choice), and then consider sequences of bits generated by iterating $f$ over $x_0$, returning a $0$ if $f^n(x_0)\leq 1/2$ and returning a $1$ if $f^n(x_0)>1/2$.

Does there exist an algorithm which, when given the parameter of the map $f$ and some bit sequence $s \in \{0, 1\}^n$ obtained by iterating $f$ over $x_0$ and returning bits in the specified manner for a total of $n$ times, that can predict the next bit obtained from $f^{n+1}(x_0)$ with non-negligible probability, *for any $n$, even when $n >|x_0|$* where $|x_0|$ is the length of the bit-string representing $x_0$?

The reason I am asking this is because it seems to be different from asking if there exists a PRG (but I could be wrong).  The reason is that I assumed the "secret" initial condition $x_0$ was not randomly chosen from a finite set, but rather was chosen from an infinite set $X$ (even though $X$ is countable and hence every element can be represented by a finite bit string).  Hence, I am wondering if this assumption about how the initial condition was drawn changes things.

Comment: @fgrieu that is correct, I meant to iterate $f$, thanks for pointing that out!  I have changed the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part of this answer is for an [earlier version of the question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/96548/2), with $x_0$ a rational represented by an arbitrarily large bitstring.

There exists functions $f$ such that no algorithms can predict the next bit of the output sequence.

A simple example is $f(x)=\begin{cases}2x&\text{if }x<1/2\\2x-1&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.
With this function, the binary sequence produced is the¹ binary representation of $x_0$ (starting at the first bit after decimal point), which can't be predicted. Is that $f$ "*a chaotic map*"? I can't tell.

We can make $f$ continuous, e.g. $f(x)=\begin{cases}2x&\text{if }x<1/2\\2-2x&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.
The relation between a binary representation of $x_0$ and the sequence remains such that changing the $i^\text{th}$ bit of that binary representation of $x_0$ changes the $i^\text{th}$ bit of the sequence. I think I have seen this function, or a close cousin, dubbed "*a chaotic map*".

We can make $f$ indefinitely derivable with $f(x)=\frac{43}{11}\,x\,(1-x)$ (a case of "*the logistic map with rational parameter*", and "*a chaotic map*" by most accounts). Without proof: for any bitstring in $\{0,1\}^{n+1}$ there exists an $x_0$ such that the first $n+1$ bits output are that bitstring, thus the next bit is not predictable with certainty.

---

Now for the [revised question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/96548/3) with

> *for any $n$, even when $n >|x_0|$* where $|x_0|$ is the length of the bit-string representing $x_0$.

Without proof: with $f(x)=\frac{43}{11}\,x\,(1-x)$ and most $x_0$, the question's generator requires work exponential in the number of bits produced (argument: $f^n(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $2^n$, thus  it seems that evaluating it to a give accuracy requires knowing $x$ with an exponential number of bits). Thus the question's generator does not meet the standard criteria of being a Polynomial-Time algorithm, and thus does not meet the standard definition of a PRG, regardless of predictability. At least, the cost and memory requirement grows so fast that it's not useful in practice.

On the other hand, for most fixed $x_0$ (perhaps, all those that do not make the bit sequence generated ultimately periodic), it's possible to make a partial predictor. In particular, the output sequence is sizably biased towards $1$. Thus a distinguisher is much easier than computing the sequence. I think that simple fixes like changing the threshold $1/2$ to the expected mean still will allow a polynomial-time distinguisher simply by computing the frequency of sequences of a number of bits.

---

¹ For numbers with two binary representations, that is of the form $a/2^k$, take the lexicographically first: e.g. $3/4$ is $.1011111111111111111…$

Comment: This is just what I was thinking. I think you can make the "unguessable" part more rigorous by arguing about the measure of the values of $X_0$ that produce each next output being equal.

Comment: And even though this answer is much more about the general case than any particular iterative function, if a PRNG is not better than just returning digits of the seed that's not a good sign.

Comment: Thanks for your response, although what I had in mind was a function  where its binary output is not predictable given ANY length of output, even when the output is longer than the binary representation of the initial condition $x_0$.  I amended the question to reflect this.

Comment: Yes, but your conclusion is "not predictable with certainty" and I'm saying you can adapt this to get to the stronger "not predictable with prob > 1/2"

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I marked the question as resolved, although I will remark that the choice of parameter 43/11 is odd, as it is greater than four and hence the function no longer satisfies the requirement that it maps X to itself, in fact it is no longer chaotic with such a parameter.  Also, if the generator did not require exponential work, then would the definition of a PRNG be satisfied, even though the initial condition was taken from an infinite set?

Comment: @GEG: $43/11$ is just _below_ $4$. It's chosen to be in the chaotic region. The definition of a PRG requires it to be expanding, and that allows a seed of size that grows with $n$ (e.g. representable as $s=x_0\,2^{n/2}$ over $n/2$ bits. We still get about twice more bits out than in. The main issue is that with the logistic map, I see not polynomial time algorithm to evaluate $n$ bits, and the bits are distinguishable from random, including biased.